# I'm working on an exercise the goal is to print out "steve" and "bill" from code academy and it only print out one name not two

Tags: javascript

Here is my code, I have checked in sintac validators http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html
http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home
and webmatrix but it was no help.

The result im getting is undefined and one of the names according the order.

```
var friends = {

    steve : {
    firstName:'Steve',
    lastName:'Jobs',
    number: '5555 8888',
    address: [ 'car', 'USA','LA','trashcan'] },

    bill : {
    firstName:'Bill',
    lastName:'Gates',
    number:'3333 4444',
    address:['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']
     }

 }

 var list = function(friends){
    for (var key in friends)
    friends[key];
    console.log(key);

 };
 list();
```

Comment: You declare `friends` as a parameter but don't pass it as an argument. Either pass it or remove the parameter and access it by the scope chain instead.

Comment: It worked like a charm, this community is awesome, really going to dedicate time for this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following

```
var list = function(friends){
     var friendName = [];
    for(var prop in friends){
        friendName.push(friends[prop]['firstName']);
    }
  return friendName;
}

list();
```

Answer (score 1):

In a multiple line block you have to use braces:

```
var list = function(friends){
    for (var key in friends) {
        friends[key];
        console.log(key);
    }
};
```

Otherwise your block be executed like:

```
var list = function(friends){
    for (var key in friends) {
        friends[key];
    }

    console.log(key);
};
```

And `key` used in `console.log` will be undefined.

What @Oriol said is true. You're no passing `friends` to your `list()` function. So you `frieds` param inside the function will be `undefined` and will overwrite the global `friends`. Or you remove the param or you pass the global `friends` to the function like:

```
list(friends);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `console.log` is not inside your `for`. Without braces, a `for` will only use the 1st line which is `friends[key]` which is doing nothing. Try this instead:

```
for (var key in friends)   
    console.log(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are specifiying your list function with a parameter `friends: var list = function(friends)`

Just change your function to :

```
var list = function(friends){
    for (var key in friends)
       console.log(key);
 };
```

and call it with `list(friends)`